# Same Image but different show

Tags: android, image, layout, background

I'm trying to copy a layout for an exercise but I'm facing a problem :

At the left of the screen it's original layout and on the right the layout that I'm trying to do

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/8fc428dc064e138ee1386832477017c2.png]

As you can see all the button on my copy program isn't the same as the original despite using the same source image and also almost the same code.
http://i.gyazo.com/ace569d7902c1b5cf4b1aedaa4d583c9.png

So what make this difference ?

Comment: Are you sure that your button images are png?

Comment: Yes as you can see my project : http://i.gyazo.com/b32b59df3c803e882b202c6642d2d708.png
The project source
http://i.gyazo.com/aed0aae071b2bd9823137443e826952b.png

Comment: Can you share me one of the image name used here. The one with whom you are having problem

Comment: Here is the picture uploaded :
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/11/1426439351-bleu.png